# Scala error: constructor is defined twice

Tags: scala, constructor

Why doesn't this compile?

```
class Name(val name: Int, val sub: Int) {

  def this() {
    this(5, 5)
  }

  def this(name: Int) {
    this(name, 5)
  }

  def this(sub:Int){
    this(5, sub)
  }
}
```

Error:

```
.scala:15: error: constructor Name is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '.scala'
  def this(sub:Int){
      ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two constructors which are essential same.

```
def this(name: Int) {
this(name, 5)
}

def this(sub:Int){
this(5, sub)
}
```

The signature of each constructor should be different, having a different variable name does not make these two constructors different.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because you have two constructors that both take a single `Int` as an argument.

To understand why it's a problem, ask yourself what should happen if you did `new Name(2)`.  Should it be the same as `new Name(2,5)` or `new Name(5,2)`? And how would the compiler know which one you wanted?

Here's a suggestion for how you can use Scala's default argument capabilities to do what you want:

```
class Name(val name: Int = 5, val sub: Int = 5)

new Name()
new Name(2, 2)
new Name(name=2)
new Name(sub=2)
```